# Database on a server without installation?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, networking

Right now I am having a customer who is working with several businesses. He is working with their data but is not allowed to directly access their databases. We thought of using SQLite or SQL CE and storing a copy/part of the original database as a file on a network share. Now the problem is that SQL CE is not supporting it and SQLite highly recommends not to do so.

First of all the performance is a huge problem, since our customer is working with a lot of data (up to several gb). The second problem is that SQLite has problems (actually the underlying os functionality for file locking is the problem) with concurrent usage of the database, when it is stored on a network share. I did a lot of research on that topic and many people say that it is just a matter of time that the database gets currupt.

Does anyone know a better solution to that problem or a workaroung which lets me use SQLite? It does not need to be a file based database, as long as nothing needs to be installed or run on the server.

Thanks, David.

Comment: "He is working with their data but is not allowed to directly access their databases". I'm wondered they are allowed to use programming languages to compose programs, and even computers to perform calculations.

Comment: I don't understand, if you cannot install anything you can surely use SQL CE which is embedded and runs in the same process of your application. Wha does the database need to be in a network share? Is there already any other application using it. If you need multiple instances of your application to access the same data shared somewhere you _do_ need a DB Server, embedded approach is not good anymore in that case.

Comment: David, if they need to work in a shared fashion just tell them they should install SQL Server (Express Edition is for free) or any other database server.

Comment: @zerkms same here... i am also wondered... if data security is a issue then u can have many option... but u can never store data in file utimatly u have to connect to the db... i dont thing ny other way possible.

Comment: So how is your customer getting access to these other people's data?  Are they providing him with an export?  CSV file?  Or is that your actual question?  What is he doing with the data once he gets it?

Comment: forget about it. If you have Filebased DB's with some GB's which should be accessed by multiple connections you will have unsolvable concurrency probolems (especially on a network share which is even slower)

Comment: Our customer is supplied with the data (e.g. a SQL dump or CSV). He is not allowed to store it on his own computer device and he is not allowed to install software on their server. he is just allowed to access a network share. this is the problem that we need to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to store data on a network share and have concurrent users accessing it you are going to need a db that can handle concurrent access. MS Access will quickly die if under concurrent access as will SQL Lite.

SQL Server Express is free and works very well. PostgreSQL as suggested by Maxim is an open source full featured db that will do the job very well but may be overkill.

You could also look at Redis ... fast lightweight in memory no sql db that also has capability to persist to file.

Comment: We thought about SQL Server Express, but as I said, our customer is not allowed to install any software on the server of his customers. He is only provided with a copy or a part of their database which must not leave their server.

Comment: Well if you cant install _anything_ on their server I guess the only thing you can use is maybe an xml or json file/s on the network share. You might run into file locking problems tho so be careful coding the read file stuff. Is this how it will be in production or is this just a development thing?

Comment: this is how it is going to be in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/). It is very easy to configure, and is rather reliable. It also support server export/import options.

And any of this makes sense, if you client is able to get his hands on an exported database somehow.